# Can I see my unpublished game store page in the steam client?

Tags: steam, appstore

I am working on setting my steam store. I am having trouble visualizing how store and library graphics are used. It would help me if I could see the graphics as used in the steam client.

I can see the graphics using the store in beta mode in a browser:

[image: screenshot of store page]

but in the steam client, no graphics are visible:

[image: screenshot showing missing graphics]

[edit] removed store link since its not helpful

Is it possible to configure the client to show my game graphics before the store goes live?

Comment: The steam URL in your post redirected to the Steam main page - you might want to try it on your side in an incognito window to verify that it works without your login, credentials, cookies, etc & edit it as needed.

Comment: @Pikalek  The redirect is due to the store not published yet.  I can see it.  The point of including it was to show I did have store page created.  My apologizes thats not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my own experiences, unpublished games will not appear in the steam client apps--the page can be viewed in the browser if you are log in using the account that owns (will publish) the game.